# How to convert L.CanvasTiles.js from Leaflet.js 0.7 to 1.0

Tags: javascript, leaflet

What i should do to use leaflet 1.0 instead of 0.7?
I created my app based on this [tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/Sumbera/c67e5551b21c68dc8299)
So I'm using those script

```
`<script src="http://www.sumbera.com/gist/js/leaflet/canvas/L.CanvasTiles.js"></script>`
```

to extend L.CanvasTiles. 
This is working nice in leaflet 0.7, but I can't convert it to leaflet 1.0.
Have You any ideas what should I do?

I have this error while changing leaflet 0.7 t o 1.0:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined(anonymous function)
Uncaught TypeError: L.canvasTiles is not a function
```

Comment: Leaflet 1.0 introduces breaking changes in the API. Apparently sumbera's Canvas Tile implementation has to modified. Could you make this a jsfiddle/jsbin?